# Correcting for multiple tests in datasets with auto-correlation (in R)?

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-comparisons, autocorrelation

I'm interested in analyzing some time-series data. In this case, the time-series is summarized into a sequence of time-bins, and I want to perform a statistical test at each time-bin, in order to determine the temporal locus of some effect.

Obviously, this would involve many statistical tests, and I should make an adjustment to control for family-wise error rate (or maybe false-discovery-rate).

A straightforward adjustment is Bonferroni or Holm's. But these kinds of tests make a "worst-case" assumption about the data that definitely does not apply in this case (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate#Resampling_procedures)):

> The procedures of Bonferroni and Holm control the FWER under any dependence structure of the p-values (or equivalently the individual test statistics). Essentially, this is achieved by assuming a `worst-case' dependence structure (which is close to an assumption of independence for all practical purposes). But such an approach generally leads to a loss of power. To give an extreme example, when all the p-values are the same (as in a case of perfect dependence), the cutoff value for the Bonferroni procedure can be taken to be simply alpha instead of alpha / m.
>
> It is therefore of interest to account for the true dependence structure of the p-values (or the individual test statistics) in order to derive more powerful procedures.

I'm wondering if there's a multiple-comparison adjustment out there that takes advantage of the auto-regressive nature of each time-bin? The wikipedia article references some methods, but (a) the first of these citations I cannot seem to access, (b) the others are very difficult to follow (I think the writing style is more focused on justifying the mathematical theorem than guiding the reader in how to implement—which is of course understandable, but I just can't follow), (c) I was hoping to find an implementation in R (or some guidance on how to do so).

I know there are other methods for dealing with the MCP (e.g., Maris & Oostenveld, 2007); but for this problem, I'm constrained a more straightforward adjustment for multiple tests.

Any help finding resources that I could get working in R would be greatly appreciated. (The closest I could find on this website is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112751/correcting-for-multiple-testing-on-non-independent-sliding-windows), and it's unanswered unfortunately.)

Comment: There seems to be an underlying statistical issue here, so I think the question is on topic, even though asking for an R package generally isn't.

Comment: [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/73974/11849) recommended Benjamini-Hochberg (1995) (see `help("p.adjust")`) when I asked a similar question.